# Why is my fill going outside the lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm a beginner in Illustrator and I’m trying to just fill in between the lines but it spilled over as shown in first pic. When I used shape builder to delete the spill it makes this weird line as shown in 2nd picture.
[image: trying to fill]

[image]

Comment: Think of fills as if they were water.... the container the fill is in, needs to be closed to retain the water.

Comment: ... just like Bruce Lee said: "be water my friend" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path should be closed if you want the fill to be contained. It makes sense too. You *can't* contain something if it's open.

Looks like you've tried Fill in one of those two curved lines and it is open. Try joining the ends of both curves so it creates one closed shape.

What the shape builder does is basically creates 2 partitions, so the color is remained inside one of them. If you see both partitions are now closed unlike your original shape.

One way to join the ends of those curves is <kbd>Cntl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (on Windows):

[image]

Note that once you join, the appearance of curve widths will also change. If you expect it to be final version of your design, I suggest you select both shapes (without fill) and `Object > Expand` them. And then use *Shape Builder* or *Paint Bucket* to fill color.

Comment: i see, i’ll try and close it. when i zoom in i see that they are touching and closed but i suppose not? i’m gonna try anyways

Comment: @jasmine sometimes it might appear they are closed, but not closed actually. Try Cntrl + J to join the ends.

Comment: Even if two individual points are _directly_ stacked one-atop-the-other, unless they're _joined_ it's still not a closed shape. It sometimes helps to imagine that the art on the canvas is actually three-dimensional — a stack of two objects aren't the same thing as a single, continuously-enclosed one, even if one section physically overlaps the other. And going back to Scott's water analogy, if you were to dump a bucket of water into your shape sandwich, it would surely push apart the overlapped sections and leak out around them.